# Comparing two data sources pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, cross-reference

I have a small script that loads in *the same* csv file twice

It then iterates through one and compares it with all the entries of the other.  Since they are initially read from the exact same source, i should get a 100% match ratio.  but i dont!

Any ideas as to why this might be?

```
import pandas as pd

_new = pd.read_csv('02 dump/reputation.csv', sep=';', float_precision='round_trip')
_data = pd.read_csv('00 data/reputation.csv', sep=';', float_precision='round_trip')


def confupdate():
    print("MATCHED")

def confnew():
    print("NOT MATCHED")



for a,b in zip(_new['LAT'].values, _new['LON'].values): 
    print(a, b)

    if a in _data['LAT'].values and b in _data.columns.values:

        confupdate()

    if a not in _data['LAT'].values or b not in _data.columns.values:

        confnew()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `columns` property of a DataFrame is effectively a list of columns. You are checking to see if the latitude and longitude are present in the columns, instead of the contents of the frame itself.

Comment: Thankyou!  I realise now my initial question was a bit off as the example script is an amalgamation of a couple of attempts; one of which where the column headers themselves was the data i wanted to match against. but even though my question was a bit unclear you have actually helped me in fixing it! Many thanks